# how do I preserve the key or index of input to Spark HashingTF() function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

Based on the Spark documentation for 1.4 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/mllib-feature-extraction.html) I'm writing a TF-IDF example for converting text documents to vectors of values. The example given shows how this can be done but the input is a RDD of tokens *with no keys*. This means that my output RDD no longer contains an index or key to refer back to the original document. The example is this:

```
documents = sc.textFile("...").map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
documents = sc.textFile("...").map(lambda line: (UNIQUE_LINE_KEY, line.split(" ")))

hashingTF = HashingTF()
tf = hashingTF.transform(documents)
```

and have the resulting `tf` variable contain the `UNIQUE_LINE_KEY` value somewhere. Am I just missing something obvious? From the examples it appears there is no good way to link the `document` RDD with the `tf` RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a version of Spark from after commit `85b96372cf0fd055f89fc639f45c1f2cb02a378f` (this includes the 1.4), and use the ml API HashingTF (requires DataFrame input instead of plain RDDs), the original columns in its output. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "the original columns in its output".

Comment: What I mean is that the output dataframe includes your original input.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that IDF() doesn't support the dataframe input :(

Comment: There are transformations from DataFrames to labeled points etc if that would help.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same issue. In the example from the docs they encourage you to apply the transformations directly on the RDD.

However, you can apply the transformations on the vectors themselves and this way you can keep the keys whichever way you choose.

```
val input = sc.textFile("...")
val documents = input.map(doc => doc -> doc.split(" ").toSeq)

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf = documents.mapValues(hashingTF.transform(_))
tf.cache()
val idf = new IDF().fit(tf.values)
val tfidf = tf.mapValues(idf.transform(_))
```

Note that this code will yield RDD[(String, Vector)] instead of RDD[Vector]